# C++ constructor initialization reference assignment

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, initialization

I am sure this question has been asked before. But I cannot seem to find the exact answer that I am looking for. Basically I am trying to create an object of the class as a member of the other class and pass one of the members by reference to the owned object through the constructor. Sometimes this seems to work, other times I get a random value.

I think that I am not understanding some rudimentary rule of initialization order

Here is the code example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
private:
    int b;
    Bar c;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(int& parm);
private:
    int& b_ref;
};

Foo::Foo(): b(0), c(b)
{}

Bar::Bar(int& parm): b_ref(parm)
{}
```

What I want is for c to own a reference to b and be able see the value as it changes.

Should I not use the initialization list in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is that objects are initialised in the order of their declaration in the `class`. In this case, it means that `b` is initialised before `c`, so this code should always work correctly.

If you swapped the order of the `b` and `c` members, then the `int` referenced by `param` would not yet be initialised in the constructor of `Bar`.

Comment: Yes I just realized that my actual code had the members swapped! Thank you that was exactly the problem.